# view sqlite files on ipad

Tags: ipad, sqlite

I developed an app which uses core data and creates an sqlite database on the ipad.
For debugging reasons I would like to access the sqlite file on the ipad.

I know the "fileURLwithPath" on the ipad but do not know how to get there.

On the simulator it is easy, since I can access any sqlite file on the mac with firefox sqlite extension.

But how can I access the ipad files?

Answer (score 1):

Try using this to copy it to your mac first:

http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/